# Swift - using XCTest to test function containing closure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, xctest

I am fairly new to Swift and am currently trying to write a unit test (using XCTest) to test the following function:

```
func login(email: String, password: String)  {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let _error = error {
            print(_error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.performSegue(identifier: "loginSeg")
        }
    }
}
```

My research has identified that I need to use the XCTestExpectation functionality as XCTest executes synchronously by default meaning it won't wait for the closure to finish running (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Whats throwing me off is how I test the login function as it itself calls the asynchronous function `Auth.auth().signIn()`. I'm trying to test whether the signIn is successful.

Apologies if this has already been answered but I couldn't find an answer that directly addresses this issue.

Thanks

Update:

With some help from the answers and further research I amended by login function to use an escaping closure:

```
func login(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping(Bool)->())  {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let _error = error {
            print(_error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        } else {
            self.performSegue(identifier: "loginSeg")
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

I then test in the following way:

```
func testLoginSuccess() {

    // other setup

    let exp = expectation(description: "Check Login is successful")

    let result = login.login(email: email, password: password) { (loginRes) in
        loginResult = loginRes
        exp.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { error in
        if let error = error {
            XCTFail("waitForExpectationsWithTimeout errored: \(error)")
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(loginResult, true)
    }
}
```

My test function now tests the login functionality successfully.

Hope this helps someone as it left me stumped for a while :)

Comment: First you need to understand what exactly you'd like to test here.
Now this function is not testable. You need to split it to testable units and write test for particular part.
Second. To avoid async calls you might want to make your code mockable, so instead of using real networking calls just fake it with needed responses.

Comment: @ilya I've updated my question to reflect that I'd like to test whether the signIn() call is successful. I'll look into mocking the network calls, that's a good idea.

Comment: OK, you added a completion parameter, but was it added only for unit testing purposes? We should not sacrifice code quality just for the sake of unit testing (I'm not saying we shouldn't do unit testing), instead we should think in isolating business logic from UI, and test the business logic. For UI we have other types of testing.

Comment: @Cristik I think it would be useful to programmatically be able to know whether or not the login functionality failed so it isn’t just for testing purposes. I’ve done some UI testing too but this wouldn’t fall into the UI category would it as I’m trying to test the actual login?

Comment: Yes, agreed, however to actually test the UI updates as expected based on the API response, a UI test would be more suitable.

Comment: @Cristik I agree, and have already got UI tests to check the segue occurs on successful login etc :)

Comment: Your update says “With some help from the answers” but you have not upvoted either answer. If the answers helped you, please upvote them, and consider clicking the check mark next to one of them to accept it.

Comment: I suppose Reebo got the wait for exceptions idea from my answer. I deleted it when I realized Jon is right. My answer doesn't test the login() function in any way. Agreed with Rob.

Comment: @robmayoff have now accepted the answer. Currently don't have permissions to upvote

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The call to Auth is an architectural boundary. Unit tests are faster and more reliable if they go up to such boundaries, but don't cross them. We can do this by isolating the Auth singleton behind a protocol.

I'm guessing at the signature of `signIn`. Whatever it is, copy and paste it into a protocol:

```
protocol AuthProtocol {
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (String, NSError?) -> Void)
}
```

This acts as a thin slice of the full Auth interface, taking only the part you want. This is an example of the Interface Segregation Principle.

Then extend Auth to conform to this protocol. It already does, so the conformance is empty.

```
extension Auth: AuthProtocol {}
```

Now in your view controller, extract the direct call to `Auth.auth()` into a property with a default value:

```
var auth: AuthProtocol = Auth.auth()
```

Talk to this property instead of directly to `Auth.auth()`:

```
auth.signIn(withEmail: email, …etc…
```

This introduces a Seam. A test can replace `auth` with an implementation that is a Test Spy, recording how `signIn` is called.

```
final class SpyAuth: AuthProtocol {
    private(set) var signInCallCount = 0
    private(set) var signInArgsEmail: [String] = []
    private(set) var signInArgsPassword: [String] = []
    private(set) var signInArgsCompletion: [(String, Foundation.NSError?) -> Void] = []

    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (String, Foundation.NSError?) -> Void) {
        signInCallCount += 1
        signInArgsEmail.append(email)
        signInArgsPassword.append(password)
        signInArgsCompletion.append(completion)
    }
}
```

A test can inject the SpyAuth into the view controller, intercepting everything that would normally go to Auth. As you can see, this includes the completion closure. I would write

- One test to confirm the call count and the non-closure arguments
- Another test to get the captured closure and call it with success.
- I'd also call it with failure, if your code didn't have a `print(_)` statement.

Finally, there's the matter of segues. Apple hasn't given us any way to unit test them. As a workaround, you can make a partial mock. Something like this:

```
final class TestableLoginViewController: LoginViewController {
    private(set) var performSegueCallCount = 0
    private(set) var performSegueArgsIdentifier: [String] = []
    private(set) var performSegueArgsSender: [Any?] = []

    override func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) {
        performSegueCallCount += 1
        performSegueArgsIdentifier.append(identifier)
        performSegueArgsSender.append(sender)
    }
}
```

With this, you can intercept calls to `performSegue`. This isn't ideal, because it's a legacy code technique. But it should get you started.

```
final class LoginViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    private var sut: TestableLoginViewController!
    private var spyAuth: SpyAuth!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        sut = TestableLoginViewController()
        spyAuth = SpyAuth()
        sut.auth = spyAuth
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
        spyAuth = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func test_login_shouldCallAuthSignIn() {
        sut.login(email: "EMAIL", password: "PASSWORD")
        
        XCTAssertEqual(spyAuth.signInCallCount, 1, "call count")
        XCTAssertEqual(spyAuth.signInArgsEmail.first, "EMAIL", "email")
        XCTAssertEqual(spyAuth.signInArgsPassword.first, "PASSWORD", "password")
    }

    func test_login_withSuccess_shouldPerformSegue() {
        sut.login(email: "EMAIL", password: "PASSWORD")
        let completion = spyAuth.signInArgsCompletion.first
        
        completion?("DUMMY", nil)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.performSegueCallCount, 1, "call count")
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.performSegueArgsIdentifier.first, "loginSeg", "identifier")
        let sender = sut.performSegueArgsSender.first
        XCTAssertTrue(sender as? TestableLoginViewController === sut,
            "Expected sender \(sut!), but was \(String(describing: sender))")
    }
}
```

Absolutely nothing asynchronous here, so no `waitForExpectations`. We capture the closure, we call the closure.

Comment: I saw your comment on my [deleted] answer. And I realized I've been doing network tests wrong. So thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. This seems like the best way to do it and has introduced me to some new concepts/practices. Look forward to the book!

Answer (score 2):

Jon's answer is excellent, I can't add comments yet, so I'll add my advice here.
For those who have (for any reason) a **static/class function instead of a singleton** or an instance function, this could help you:

For example, if you have `Auth.signIn(withEmail: emai...` where `signIn` is a static function. Instead of use:

```
var auth: AuthProtocol = Auth.auth()
```

Use:

```
var auth: AuthProtocol.Type = Auth.self
```

And assign it like this

```
sut.auth = SpyAuth.self
```